# Replicate only a few tables in PostgreSQL 10

Tags: replication, postgresql-10

I have a need to keep updated just a few tables between databases **with different purposes and schemas**, except for these few tables.

My current solution is a cron job that selects from one database and inserts into the other every minute or so, but I was wondering if there are more robust solutions around for PostgreSQL version 10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To replicate some specific tables, you can use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication.html)

Another option is to not replicate at all and access the remote tables through a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html)

Comment: Had forgotten about foreign tables! Thanks for the reminder

Comment: Also, maybe it's worth mentioning, but logical replication seems to have been added in version 10, so my question may be useful to others :)

Comment: dblink is another option.